# Hibernate, iBatis, Spring JDBC Template, which one to use?

Tags: spring, hibernate, orm, ibatis

I am developing a web app in java. I am thinking of using Spring MVC. But at ORM side, I have a decision to make. I have studied about ORMs like Hibernate,iBatis, Spring JDBC Template etc.

I find iBatis and Spring JDBC Template (using RowMapper) are almost same, where you map each query to an object. So you have to write a class for each query.

In Hibernate, you map each table with a class.It reduces the need to write SQL.

I guess Hibernate is preferable when you are not good in SQL.In my case, I am quite comfortable in SQL, so want to use iBatis or Spring JDBC Template which will give me good control over SQL and these are less complex than Hibernate.

But Hibernate provide caching which other ORMs do not provide.

So my questions:

1. Which one to use between iBatis and Spring JDBC Template?
2. Is Hibernate caching (or any other Hibernate feature which I do not know) so good that I should go with Hibernate instead of other ORMs?

Comment: Caching can be independent of ORM technology.

Answer (score 6):

> I guess Hibernate is preferable when you are not good in SQL

I disagree with the idea that you should use Hibernate, or any other ORM because you're not very good at SQL.

Whilst it's true that Hibernate will generate your SQL for you, not understanding what it's doing is a recipe for a performance disaster.

Answer (score 2):

As a Hibernate developer I am pretty good at SQL too ;)  In fact the beginning of my career was working exclusively with relational (and even some pre-relational) databases.  Anyway I really don't get this misconception that hand writing SQL being "more maintainable" or giving "better control".  But if you do buy into that misconception then you can actually tell Hibernate the SQL you want it to use for all CRUD operations pertaining to each and every entity (see `@SQLInsert`, `@SQLUpdate`, etc).

Again, I find that not nearly as maintainable.  Personally, I would much rather have Hibernate manage the INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE SQL for me.  Loading data on the other hand is a situation where I generally want a little more control.  But Hibernate (and JPA providers in general) already give you this kind of control through HQL/JPQL and Criteria queries.  In my opinion, if you are relying on Session.get you are simply asking for bad performance.  And that has nothing to do with using O/RM.  That's just not good data loading plan because the amount of data you need (even related to the same entity) is different based on the application use case.  For example, loading Employees for a drop-down list requires much different amount of data from generating a departmental roster.  And thats the control.

By all means use what feels most comfortable to you and meets the goals/requirements of the application.  Just make sure your comparison points between technologies and products are factual and not just misconception.

Caching is a fair point with regard to O/RM.  In fact JPA (as of 2.0) requires some level of caching.  However, be aware that caching at the O/RM level often leads to worse performance.  You really need to understand the semantics of the particular data you would like to cache.  Some data is good candidate for caching, some are not.  Also, it is often much better to cache "above" the O/RM level.

Personally I would choose Hibernate because I believe (1) it strikes the best balance between abstraction while still giving access to SQL power (this is largely true of JPA providers in general) and (2) it has the most complete feature set of any persistence provider out there.

Comment: Excellent points ! Just thought sharing an interview by Gaven King several years earlier where he talked about these points - http://www.javaperformancetuning.com/news/interview041.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Well, your choice should depend of what you are developing the application for. I would say that Hibernate is the more powerful among the above mentioned ORMs and has a strong community and caching is really strong. But really strong caching is sometimes a problem and has it's memory intensive.

Am a myBatis user and believe it's a mid-way and provides all that you need. Well, myBatis would be my personal choice over Spring JDBC template.